# How to dynamically add objects to objects inside of an object

Tags: javascript, object, dynamic

So I have an object: `structure = {}` and I can dynamically add an object to it with `structure[obj]`, but I need to be able to add yet another object inside of that. I tried doing `structure[obj][obj2]` but that doesn't work. What is the proper way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your code where you managed to assign objects. Just `structure[obj]` is not an assignment but an expression.

Comment: Here is the code:  
var structure = {} function addObject(object){ structure[object] = ""; } function ObjectToObject(object2,object) { structure[object][object2] = ""; } addObject("foo"); ObjectToObject("bar","foo");

Comment: Best to edit your question (for readability of the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this statement:

```
structure[object] = "";
```

You are not adding an object to `structure`, but an empty string, which is a primitive value, not an object. Also the name `object` is misleading in your code, as apparently you have a string value for it (`'foo'`). But even if it were a true object, by using it in the above statement, JavaScript will take the string value of it (which would be `'Object object'` for plain objects) and use it as a key (property) in `structure`.

Look at the whole piece of code:

```
var structure = {} 
function addObject(object){ 
    structure[object] = ""; 
} 
function ObjectToObject(object2, object) { 
    structure[object][object2] = ""; 
} 
addObject("foo"); 
ObjectToObject("bar","foo");
```

... the statement `structure[object][object2] = "";` will be without effect. It comes down to this:

```
structure.foo.bar = "";
```

As `structure.foo` is a string value, JavaScript will coerce it to a String object because otherwise it cannot apply `.bar`. So really this is what is executed:

```
new String(structure.foo).bar = "";
```

The assignment of `''` is really made, but then that temporary object is disposed again, so that you never see that `bar` again.

#### How you should do it:

Don't asssign a string in the first function, but an empty object. Also use better names for your variables:

```js
var structure = {} 
function addObject(key){ 
    structure[key] = {}; 
} 
function ObjectToObject(key2, key) { 
    structure[key][key2] = {}; 
} 
addObject("foo"); 
ObjectToObject("bar","foo");

console.log(structure);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have assigned an

```
structure["foo"] = {bar: 1}
```

You can then assign a further element like this

```
structure["foo"]["harry"] = 99;
```

But you can't do it without the first step, because structure["foo"] won't exist yet